# iPython widget : Interact doesn't work with class methods - AttributeError

Tags: python, widget, ipython, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I'm faced with a problem in the ipython notebook. I would like to implement the iphython widgets in some class meethods but it seems that it's not yet possible in the ipython v2 as  mentionned in this github issue : https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6278

Quote from fperez

> This code:
>
> ```
> from IPython.html.widgets import interact
>
> class Foo(object):
>     def show(self, x):
>         print x
>
> f = Foo()
> interact(f.show, x=(1,10))
> ```
>
> produces this exception:
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-58-b03b8685dfc0> in <module>()
>       7 f = Foo()
>       8 
> ----> 9 interact(f.show, x=(1,10))
>
> /home/fperez/usr/lib/python2.7/site->     packages/IPython/html/widgets/interaction.pyc in interact(__interact_f, >     **kwargs)
>     235         f = __interact_f
>     236         w = interactive(f, **kwargs)
> --> 237         f.widget = w
>     238         display(w)
>     239         return f
>
> AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'widget'
> ```

I tried to wrap the interact widget in a lambda function but my attempt doesn't seem to work

```
def constructWidgets(self):
    interact(lambda a:self.getWidgetValue(a),a=widgets.FloatSliderWidget(min=-10.0, max=10.0, step=0.1, value=5.0, description="WidgetNameFoo"))
```

I have got this error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'WidgetNameFoo'
```

I understand that I have a conflict between the description field (in this case 'WidgetNameFoo') and the variable name 'a'. When the description field mathches the variable name, ipython doesn't return the TypeError message. For example :

```
def constructWidgets(self):
    interact(lambda a:self.getWidgetValue(a),a=widgets.FloatSliderWidget(min=-10.0, max=10.0, step=0.1, value=5.0, description="a"))
```

I need to transmit a description field which varies depends on the case.

Thanks for your help ! =)

Comment: The second error (unexpected keyword argument) is a bug that was recently fixed: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7507 . For now, don't pass a `description` argument to widgets used with interact().